# Magento 2: Remove Checkout Options

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

How do I remove the (required) Phone Number input from the Checkout page? I don't need my customers to enter their number and don't want it to put them off from checking out.

Comment: Does anything [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html) help?

Comment: We can try this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115826/magento-2-customising-checkout-page-not-working/115900#115900

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the instructions on the Magento site but the items aren't being removed.

I created `checkout_index_index.xml` and placed it in `VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/`

The `checkout_index_index.xml` looks like the below:

```
<body>

    <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>

</body>
```