# Magento 2: Customising Checkout page – not working!

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml

I am trying to remove input fields (Company and Telephone) from the Checkout page. I have followed what is explained on the M2 site [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html) under 'Disable a component'. I have done the below but nothing is changing on the Checkout page:

I copied the `checkout_index_index.xml` file from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/` and placed it in `VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/`.

I updated this new file (`checkout_index_index.xml`) by adding the below to the `company` item:

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Resulting in it looking like this:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
   </item>
   <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

Once I saved this file, I deleted all the content from:

```
var/di
pub/static/
var/cache/ 
var/generation/
var/page_cache/ 
var/view_preprocessed/
```

Then ran:

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
php magento cache:clean
```

Refreshed the browser... and nothing. No change at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at examples [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html)?

Comment: @ Steve Johnson, seem the guide from document didn't work for us. You have any new guide or explain more details?

Comment: did you find the solution? please share if you did because i'm facing the same issue.